# Grouping questions (and answers)

Tags: discussion

A few month ago I [asked a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19828/insert-key-words-key-phrases-into-toc) on this website that was answered perfectly. And a couple of days ago I asked [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24184/hyperref-ize-the-keywords-in-toc) that was answered as well and that builds up on the previous one.

Now I wonder how I could put them together in a way that other users can see both questions and answers as soon as they decide to take a look at one of them.

Shall I just copy them into one?
Shall I provide a link in each one?
Is there a certain device in this website that is made for this situation?

For any ideas I am very thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please ask questions about the site on the Meta site. You can link both questions together by placing a link on one of them to the other in the question or in an answer or comment. All linked question will then appear on top of the sidebar. Note that in questions and answer posts you can simply paste the question link into the text and it will be automatically formatted.

Answer (score 3):

To expand a little on what Martin said: if there are questions that you think should be connected, then the correct way is to ensure that each is linked from the other by a hyperlink.  It is a good idea to provide some context, but exactly what that should be depends on the nature of the connection.  (I haven't looked at the questions you link, so this shouldn't be taken prescriptive in any fashion!)  For example, if one question builds on another, then it can start with, "Following on from my question ...".  But if a question is merely related, the link should be near the end, as in, "A similar question is ..." (perhaps with a sentence as to why).
The links should not be intrusive, so not cluttered with too much extra context.  Just enough so that someone can make an assessment as to whether or not to click on the link.